# Add a custom-made slideshow to Wordpress Theme

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

So i made a slideshow using HTML, CSS and JS.

It's for a personal blog i'm creating, so i would like to add the slideshow into a Wordpress theme that i purchased.

I created a child theme and tried to edit the function.php file and the style.css, and although i know some PHP it's really hard to understand how the code works and where to add mine.

Basically i want to display my slideshow initially, and then the rest of the Wordpress theme with all the posts and such.

Is it possible or should i only work with the customization options of the theme, although they're limited?

Comment: Have you tried any slideshow plugins?

Comment: I'm sure there are some, but is it possible to customize it completely with my code?

Comment: Oh, I see, you want to use your code... then no, that's unlikely that it would work. If you have specific questions about the child theme, you should reference your code and specific issues about what's not working in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've gone with a child theme,  may I suggest copying a page template from the parent into your child theme?

Then you can copy your code for the slideshow via the editor into your child theme's copy of page template and use said template throughout your website for whatever page you'd like without colliding with parent theme updates.

Here's a relatively simple tutorial for creating a page template:
https://www.cssigniter.com/add-custom-page-template-using-child-theme/